# string members don't work with string from file separated by delimiter

Tags: c++, ifstream

This code is supposed to print part of the string and it's last character, however the second part after delimiter(:) only prints the string and not the character. Why doesn't it work, and how can i fix this?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
string info;
void PrintTextFile(){
    ifstream myfile("example.txt");
    if(myfile.is_open()){
        while (getline(myfile, info, ':')){
            cout << info << "   " << info.back() << "\n";    
        }
        myfile.close();
    }
    else {
        cout << "Unable to open file.";
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {    
    PrintTextFile();
    return 0;
}
```

example.txt:

```
Left1:Right1
Left2:Right1
Left3:Right3
```

My output:

```
Left1        1
Right1
Left2        2
Right2
Left3        3
Right3
```

Expected output:

```
Left1        1
Right1       1
Left2        2
Right2       2
Left3        3
Right3       3
```

Comment: What output do you expect? Please [edit] the question and make that clear _there_

Comment: Think hard about what what a `getline` hunting for a `:` will accumulate before the *next* `:` in that *specific* stream. Remember, it will *not* stop at newlines; it will skip/stop on specified delimiters or EOF *only*. Your first string, then, is "Left1". The next string is "Right1\nLeft2", etc. Now do you understand your associated output?

Comment: Fixed the question to include the expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue here is that when you provide your own delimiter to `getline` it stops  using a newline as a delimiter. That means in your first loop you read in `Left1:`, discard the `:` and `info` is left with `Left1`.  The second iteration you again read until you see an `:` so you read in `Right1\nLeft2:`, discard the `:` which leave `info` with `Right1\nLeft2`.

What you need to do is to either read in the entire line and then use a stringstream to parse it out like

```
while (getline(myfile, info)){
    stringstream ss(info)
    while (getline(ss, info, ':') // this works now because eof will also stop getline
        cout << info << "   " << info.back() << "\n";    
}
```

Or since you know you just need to two values, get them both by reading each part of the line like

```
while (getline(myfile, info, ':')){
    cout << info << "   " << info.back() << "\n";  
    getline(myfile, info);
    cout << info << "   " << info.back() << "\n";  
}
```